# How to combine columns form two different pipe delimited filea using unix. I need to pick columns from both file and merge into one output file

Tags: unix, scripting

I am trying to write a logic in unix scripting where I am merging columns form 2 pipe delimited file. For example, I have file a.txt with columns A|B|C and file b.txt which has columns D|E|F. I want the output file c.txt with columns A|D|B|C|E|F.

Thanks!!
Sourabh

Comment: What is the logic? First rows of both files, then second ones etc.?

Comment: Please elaborate the logic to merge the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use paste to match up the two files, and then awk to output the
columns in the order desired.

```
$ cat a
A|B|C
1|2|3
$ cat b
D|E|F
4|5|6
$ paste -d'|' a b | awk -F'|' 'BEGIN { OFS="|" }{print $1, $4, $2, $3, $5, $6}'
A|D|B|C|E|F
1|4|2|3|5|6
```

Answer (score 0):

try in a single awk command too now.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{A[FNR]=$1;$1="";B[FNR]=$0;next} {v=$1;$1="";print A[FNR],v B[FNR] $0}' OFS="|"  a.txt b.txt
```

Will add explanation shortly too.